# What do I do with a question that's misleading once the answer has been found?

Tags: discussion, etiquette, subjective

I asked [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/20412/how-to-boot-into-command-line-mode-and-keep-other-services-unchanged) yesterday on SU. Some sleep and few hours of investigation later, I know the actual issue and the solution, both of which I've posted in an answer. If you read the question now, you'll realize that in its current form it is misleading.

I'd delete the question but I think the information is relevant. I also found a similarly misleading [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78408/how-do-i-change-default-runlevel-in-ubuntu) over at SO when researching this.

What's the best way to handle such questions? I've already edited the question to indicate the problem lies elsewhere, but should I do more? Do I delete the question? Should I accept my own answer or is that bad form? Should I modify the question to reflect the true problem, even if turns the other answer completely irrelevant (at best)?

Comment: God killed 6 ponies because of you! http://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/11971/list

Comment: Alright, pipe down. What a gawdalmighty ruckus. Edited so as not to offend delicate sensibilities.

Comment: I wouldn't consider those sensibilities to be "delicate" more... "anal". But seriously, don't do it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would argue that if you made a mistake and then found out the problem was something unrelated then its more than likely that you aren't (or won't be) the only person to have that problem.

I would leave the question largely as it is with an edited section at the bottom (which appears to be what you've now done), answer it and accept your own answer.

Remember people may find your question via Google and other means. They may follow the same thought process as you and use the kind of search terms as were/are in your original question so try to keep the question in a form where if you'd searched for an answer originally you would've found your own question, if that makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

If you accept your own answer on a misleading question, that would appear like you're gaming the system for an accepted answer.

You could close as no longer relevant if it is so.

But as an information repository, you could just leave it and not accept an answer.

Comment: After all this time, didn't know that.